# JavaFX GridPane styling particular cell

Tags: css, javafx-2

I have GridPane and calling `gridPane.setStyle("...")` to set style to whole pane. My goal is to add border to each column. Is there any possibility to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's possible using simply CSS. Some people have already discussed this subject here, with some solution : https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2384973.

Comment: What was the solution? That url is down

Answer (score 2):

In case the link in Teocali's answer does go down in the future, the proposed solution is to set a background color for the GridPane and adding gaps. Adding gaps can be done by setting the -fx-hgap and -fx-vgap properties in the css style of the GridPane, or by its modifying vgap and hgap properties in FXML.

Then you can use a StackPane to wrap each of the columns in the GridPane and set a different background color in the StackPane style.